# Plotting periodic ranges of data using gnuplot every option

Tags: gnuplot

I have a 1-column text file and need to skip 8000 lines and plot the next 1000 lines and so on until the end of the file. So, was wondering what would be the right values to set for `every` option in `Gnuplot` for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stats 'file.dat'
n=STATS_records/9000
plot for [i=0:n] 'file.dat' every ::i*9000+8000::i*9000+8999 w p lc 1 notitle
```

You have to decide what do you want to do with files containing number of rows that can't divide by 9000.

---

**Note** that the first data-line/record in the file has the index 0.